# Cannot get index.php page to display in docker container

Tags: php, docker, nginx

I have a docker container that I setup to display a php page, however it displays a 403 forbidden page. I have nginx running on my host machine and I enabled my site as well. The site is displaying html file but not php files. I also verified the following services are running.

1. nginx is running in the docker container
2. php-fpm service is running in the docker container.
3. the user www-data has permissions to execute files in the folder

```
    server {
      listen 443;
      server_name af.oxygenweb.ca;


      ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/af.oxygenweb.ca/fullchain.pem;
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/af.oxygenweb.ca/privkey.pem;

      ssl_stapling on;
      ssl_stapling_verify on;


      location /.well-known {
         alias /var/www/html/.well-known;
      }


      access_log   /var/log/nginx/af/access.log;
      error_log    /var/log/nginx/af/error.log;

      location / {
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.php;
        proxy_pass http://172.17.0.2;
        proxy_redirect http:// https://;
        proxy_connect_timeout 300s;
        proxy_read_timeout 300s;
        #try_files $uri /index.html index.php;
      }

      # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server

      location ~* \.php$ {
          # include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
          # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        include         fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked error logs?

Comment: Also, this two lines are missing `root /var/www/html` and `index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html` from your nginx config.

Comment: @AnkurTiwari I did a `tail -f /var/log/nginx/af/error.log` too. But I don't see anything. Also, you can find the missing `root /var/www/html` under `location / {` with the `index index.php;`